# How to run multiple application on Grunt

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, server

I have two applications say `applicationA` and `applicationB` and if I run following command on terminal

```
grunt serve
```

my one `applicationA` will up and work fine.

when i need to run `applicationB`, first i need to stop `applicationA` and then i can run `applicationB`. If i try to run both then its complaining like this

```
Fatal error: Port 9000 is already in use by another process.
```

Note: port on which it run is `9000`, one application is in `angularJS` and other contains static pages

So my question is that can I run multiple applications on `Grunt` in parallel? if yes then please guide me how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading @NLN answer where He mentioned that

> make sure each of them use different port number

So i have start reading my `Gruntfile.js` file. In this file there is a `connect` object defined like this in `applicationA`

```
grunt.initConfig({
   connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000, 
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35729 
      }
   }    
});
```

so in other `applicationB` i have change this configuration `port` and `livereload` like this

```
grunt.initConfig({
   connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9001, // change to some different port
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35730 // this also need to change to some different port
      }
   }    
});
```

And it worked for me. May it will also help someone else :)

Answer (score 2):

> So my question is that can I run multiple applications on Grunt in
>   parallel? if yes then please guide me how can i do that

Yes you can run multiple application through grunt(from separate terminal windows), **but make sure each of them use different port number**

You may register the grunt task as follows:

```
grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'applicationA') {
        return grunt.task.run([ 
            'express:appA',
        ]);
    }
    return grunt.task.run([
           'express:appB',
         ]);
  });
```

Which would run applicationA as `grunt serve:applicationA` and applicationB as `grunt serve:applicationB`

Hope its clear!

Comment: Are you sure from your code i can run multiple applications in parallel ? because code is saying one will return either appA or appB

Comment: From terminal-one, use `grunt serve:applicationA`, and open another terminal and use `grunt serve:applicationB`

Comment: i have tried what you have guided me, in one terminal its running fine but in other its saying : Fatal error: Port 9000 is already in use by another process. and its logical because one application has ran on 9000 port

Comment: I repeat, you need to use separate ports for both applications. Which server are you using ? If its express, find and change this line `app.listen(port-number)` in both applications.

Comment: you said "need separate ports". this gives me clue. and i have tried to change ports and it worked. i have also posted an answer where i have explained what i have change in which file. and it worked! Thanks!.

Comment: @MuhammadSuleman you must upvote and accept an answer if you find it useful, so that it can help others as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure grunt to run in another port by updating your `Gruntfile`:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  server: {
    port: grunt.option('port') || 8000
  }
});
```

Or from the command line:

```
$ grunt serve --port=8000
```

Comment: for changing port its complaining: Fatal error: Port 35729 is already in use by another process. what next ?

Comment: 9000 port is using by default

Answer (score 1):

If someone uses watch in grunt and the error still says 'Port is already used by some process', you will also have to change the lines `livereload:true` to `livereload:9001` in watch of GruntFile.js on one server.

Answer (score 0):

First change port numbers as suggested by @Muhammad Suleman

after that, if problem persist, change ***livereload:false*** in application A and keep ***livereload:true*** in application B.

```
options: {                    
           livereload: false
          }
```

**P.S.**- sublime text 2 problem related to livereload solve by this.